# программа которая издает звук

Tags: javascript, c++

помогите создать программу которая издает звук частоты которую я задам.я знаю немного javascript, но даже не представляю как это реализовать, и можно еще на C++ подсказать.

Comment: лучше было на два вопроса разбить, слишком разные способы, и на C++ зависит от платформы

Answer (score 3):

Для JavaScript можно воспользоваться Audio API. Есть [ряд примеров на англоязычном сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep).

Для C++ очень многое зависит от конкретной платформы. Например, для Windows вполне может подойти стандартная функция [beep из Win API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: я с преподавателем очень давно создавал подобную програма на Turbo Pascal и там не нужно было что-то вроде такого..

Comment: Только со времён Turbo Pascal прошло уже, мягко говоря, очень много времени. Технологии и подходы с тех пор сильно изменились.